# Android - asynchttpclient send back resul from onSuccess or onFailure

Tags: android, callback, android-async-http

Hy!

I want to make some http calls to a restserver from my android client. I created a class for rest calls.
I followed the http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ description:

My question is that how can I send back anything from onSucces() method? For example I have the following function:

```
public class RestController {
    public String getName() throws JSONException {

        TwitterRestClient.get(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            String name;
            try {
                name = response.getString("name");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
       });
   }
}
```

How can I return the name to getName function?

```
function () {
  ...
  String name = restController.getName();
  ...
  do something with the name
```

Thank you very much!
I will apreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Use interface as a callback, its an async call so you will not get result immediately

Comment: Can you explain a bit how can I do it? I don't understand very well how these async stuff works. :/

Comment: AsyncTask - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I know this, but in my case is not exactly Asynctask, or it is? I want that my function(getName) to return the http call result, but I can't pass from onSuccess out to getName function

Comment: What is your name? this link opens my skype, not a chat :(